# how to use isConnected in Bluetooth API?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Bluetooth API state that there is method call " isConnected()" but when I use it, it showed error which said this method is undefined for Bluetooth socket. Could some expert point me out how "isConnected" should be used?

Here is the code :

```
do
{
    count++;
    if (m_btSck.isConnected())
        break;
} while ((Connect(m_nRoboDev)!=0) && (count <15));
```

Comment: can you upload the code please ?